# How to open chrome://extensions/

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a question that I want to open chrome://extensions/ page by other programs, such as cmd.exe, or other else.

As we know, if we use chrome.exe open a website, we can execute “C:\XXX\chrome.exe www.test.com" in cmd.exe, then it will open www.test.com page. But it doesn't work in chrome://extensions/ page. Since chrome://extensions/ is a local page.

I also tried others solutions, such as window.open("chrome://extensions/"), chrome.tabs.create(), and so on.

Comment: similar http://superuser.com/questions/558672/open-chrome-and-launch-the-settings-page

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.tabs.create` will work in a context of an extension (unlike `window.open`, which is unprivileged). Doesn't even require the `"tabs"` permission.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://extensions/"});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You're right, we can open chrome://extensions/ page in an extension with your method.